# Moving blocks down y axis in pygame tetris clone

Tags: pygame, tetris

Through some trial and error, I have decided to draw each of the four Tetris blocks for each shape as their own sprites on separate surfaces.  There is a main pivot block in which the other 3 blocks get their y position.  Currently working on getting the shape to stop at bottom of screen OR if collision with other blocks at bottom of screen.  The movement is controlled in update_shape().  If there is a collison on the rect.bottom of the bottom facing blocks, the movement must stop.  Any ideas?  Sorry in advance, my OOP is newbie level at best!

```
import pdb

import random
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import (
        K_ESCAPE, K_SPACE, 
        K_c, K_x, K_z, 
        K_UP, K_DOWN, K_RIGHT, K_LEFT, K_F1,
        K_RSHIFT, K_LSHIFT, K_RCTRL, K_LCTRL,

        QUIT, KEYDOWN, KEYUP
        )


VERSION = 0.25

# Colors
BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0) 
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)
RED      = ( 255,   0,   0)
GREEN    = (   0, 255,   0)
BLUE     = (   0,   0, 255)
CYAN     = (   0, 255, 255)
YELLOW   = ( 255, 255,   0)
PURPLE   = ( 128,   0, 128)
ORANGE   = ( 255, 165,   0)
PINK     = ( 255,   0, 255)

# Screen dimensions
SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT  = 432, 720 # 18 x 30

# Frames Per Second
# 
FPS = 20

# Gravity
# Gravity = G 
#1G = 1 cell per frame
# 0.1G = 1 cell per 10 frames
# TODO - how does this work? 
GRAVITY = 2

# tilesize for blocks and grid for playfield and game screen
TILESIZE = 24

###############################################################################
class SingleBlock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ base class for block sprite """
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.tile = TILESIZE

        # initial start for block
        self.pivot_x = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2
        self.pivot_y = 0

        # 7 block types (this will be order for all block data)
        self.block_types = ['t', 'j', 'z', 'o', 's', 'l', 'i']
        self.block_colors = [PURPLE, BLUE, RED, YELLOW, GREEN, ORANGE, CYAN]

        # coordinates for each shape 
        # (excludes pivot block which is auto drawn by function)
        self.block_coords = [
                [[ 0, -1], [-1,  0], [ 1,  0]], # 0 tu
                [[ 0, -1], [ 1,  0], [ 0,  1]], # 1 tr
                [[-1,  0], [ 1,  0], [ 0,  1]], # 2 td spawn
                [[ 0, -1], [-1,  0], [ 0,  1]], # tl 3
                [[ 0, -1], [-1,  1], [ 0,  1]], # jl 4
                [[-1, -1], [-1,  0], [ 1,  0]], # ju 5
                [[ 0, -1], [ 1, -1], [ 0,  1]], # jr 6
                [[-1,  0], [ 1,  0], [ 1,  1]], # jd 7 spawn
                [[-1,  0], [ 0,  1], [ 1,  1]], # zh 8 spawn
                [[ 1, -1], [ 1,  0], [ 0,  1]], # zv 9
                [[-1,  0], [-1,  1], [ 0,  1]], # o  10
                [[ 1,  0], [-1,  1], [ 0,  1]], # sh 11 spawn
                [[ 0, -1], [ 1,  0], [ 1,  1]], # sv 12
                [[ 0, -1], [ 0,  1], [ 1,  1]], # lr 13
                [[-1,  0], [ 1,  0], [-1,  1]], # ld 14 spawn
                [[-1, -1], [ 0, -1], [ 0,  1]], # ll 15 
                [[-1,  0], [ 1,  0], [ 1, -1]], # lu 16
                [[ 0, -2], [ 0, -1], [ 0,  1]], # iv 17
                [[-2,  0], [-1,  0], [ 1,  0]]  # ih 18 spawn
                ]

    def draw_single_block(self, color, x, y):
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((self.tile, self.tile))
        self.surf.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(left=x, top=y)
        outline_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.tile, self.tile)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surf, BLACK, outline_rect, 2)

    def make_shape(self, shape_index, color_index):
        self.shape_index = shape_index

        # draw Pivot block and add to groups
        self.P = PivotBlock(color_index)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.P)
        self.moving.add(self.P)

        # Create three blocks and add to groups
        self.three_blocks = []
        for block in range(3):
            block = CoupledBlocks(self.block_coords[self.shape_index][block][0],
                                  self.block_coords[self.shape_index][block][1],
                                  color_index)
            self.all_sprites.add(block)
            self.moving.add(block)
            self.three_blocks.append(block)






    def handle_events(self, pressed_keys):

        if pressed_keys[K_UP] or pressed_keys[K_x]:
            self.rotate_clockwise()

        if pressed_keys[K_LCTRL] or pressed_keys[K_RCTRL] or pressed_keys[K_z]:
            self.rotate_counter_clockwise()

        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.left_shift()
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.right_shift()
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.non_locking_soft_drop()
        if pressed_keys[K_SPACE]:
            self.hard_drop()
        if pressed_keys[K_LSHIFT] or pressed_keys[K_RSHIFT] or pressed_keys[K_c]:
            self.hold()
        if pressed_keys[K_F1]:
            self.pause()


        if self.rect.centery > SCREEN_HEIGHT - (self.tile * 1.5):
            self.rect.centery = SCREEN_HEIGHT - (self.tile * 1.5)
        else:
            self.block_fall()



    def block_fall(self):
        """ changes y by Gravity """


    def rotate_clockwise(self):
        """ Up arrow or X """
        pass

    def rotate_counter_clockwise(self):
        """ Ctrl or Z """
        pass

    def left_shift(self):
        """ Left arrow """
        pass
    def right_shift(self):
        """" Right arrow """
        pass

    def non_locking_soft_drop(self):
        """ Down arrow """
        pass

    def hard_drop(self):
        """ space bar """
        pass

    def hold(self):
        """ Shift or C """
        pass

    def pause(self):
        """ Esc or F1 """
        pass


    def update_shape(self):
        #print(self.moving)

        for block in self.moving:
            print(block)
            print(block.rect)
            #for hits in pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.moving, self.stopped, False, False):

            if block.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:


                self.stopped.add(block)
                self.moving.remove(block)
                block.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT

            else:
                self.P.rect.y += GRAVITY
                print(self.P.rect.y)


        for block in range(3):
            self.three_blocks[block].rect.x = (self.three_blocks[block].block_coords[self.shape_index][block][0] * self.tile) + self.P.rect.x
            self.three_blocks[block].rect.y = (self.three_blocks[block].block_coords[self.shape_index][block][1] * self.tile) + self.P.rect.y


    def update(self):
        pass
###############################################################################

class PivotBlock(SingleBlock):
    """  """
    def __init__(self, color):
        super(PivotBlock, self).__init__()


        # draw pivot block
        self.draw_single_block(self.block_colors[color], self.pivot_x, self.pivot_y)

    def update(self):
        pass

###############################################################################

class CoupledBlocks(SingleBlock):
    """  """
    def __init__(self, x_offset, y_offset, color):
        super(CoupledBlocks, self).__init__()

        self.x_offset = x_offset
        self.y_offset = y_offset

        self.my_x = (self.x_offset * self.tile) + self.pivot_x
        self.my_y = (self.y_offset * self.tile) + self.pivot_y

        self.draw_single_block(self.block_colors[color], self.my_x, self.my_y)

    def update(self):
        pass

################################################################### Game Class

class Game(SingleBlock):
    def __init__(self, width=SCREEN_WIDTH, height=SCREEN_HEIGHT, fps=FPS):
        """ Initialize pygame, window, background, font, ... """        
        super(Game, self).__init__()

        pygame.init()

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.tile = TILESIZE

        # screen, caption and background
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Block Stack Extravaganza! v' + str(VERSION))
        self.background = pygame.Surface(self.screen.get_size()).convert()
        self.background.fill(BLACK)

        # Mange how fast screen updates
        self.fps = fps
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.playtime = 0.0

        # Fonts
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('mono', 15, bold=True)

        # Create groups
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.moving = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.stopped = pygame.sprite.Group()




    def run(self):
        """ MAIN LOOP """

        # Create block type and add to groups 
        self.make_shape(10,0)

        ### MAIN LOOP #########################################################

        # Variable to keep main loop running
        running = True

        while running:

            # Events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT :
                    running = False
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        running = False
                elif event.type == KEYUP:
                    pass

            # Handle key presses
            #pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            #B.handle_events(pressed_keys)

            '''
            if not self.moving:
                self.make_shape(2,0)
            '''

            self.update_shape()



            # Update sprite groups
            for ent in self.all_sprites:
                ent.update()





            # Blit background map
            self.screen.blit(self.background, (0,0))

            # Text draw
            milliseconds = self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            self.playtime += milliseconds / 1000.0
            self.draw_text("FPS: {:6.3}{}PLAYTIME: {:6.3}SECONDS".format(self.clock.get_fps(), " "*5, self.playtime))



            # Draw all sprites
            for ent in self.all_sprites:
                self.screen.blit(ent.surf, ent.rect)
                #ent.handle_events(event)

            #BB.update()
            #self.update_shape()

            #if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, characters):

            # Flip to display current frame
            pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.quit()
        print("This game was played for {0:.2f} seconds".format(self.playtime))
        sys.exit()

    def draw_text(self, text):
        """ Center text in window """
        fw, fh = self.font.size(text)  # fw fontwidth, fh fontheight
        surface = self.font.render(text, True, (GREEN))
        self.screen.blit(surface, ((self.width - fw) // 2, (self.height - fh) // 2))

######################################################################### main 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Game().run()
```

Comment: To be more specific, if ANY of the 4 blocks collides with the bottom of the playfield (SCREEN_HEIGHT for now), all 4 blocks need to stop there.